# Calling a class-function that gets redefined, from an included Module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, module, mixins

Here's the current situation :

Core_Class is the key class which includes a lot of modules
Use_Class inherits from Core_Class

In one of the modules included by Core_Class, I want it to access a method defined in the Core_Class. This works just fine. Lets call this method header()

I am now trying to re-define this function in Use_class, so that the use_class has a unique header method.

This all looks a bit like this:

```
module Print_header
  def print_header_
    Core_Class.header()
  end
end
class Core_Class
  include Print_header
  def header()
    puts "old header"
  end
  def run
    print_header
  end
end
class Use_Class < Core_Class
  def header()
    puts "New header"
  end
  def run
    print_header
  end
end
```

Now my problem is that the old code gets used. I feel that I'm missing something about object oriented programming, inheritance and mixins, but I am unsure what. Spend about 2 hours googling it, couldn't find something to help me understand, and I'm the only Ruby(very very junior) dev in the office.

If possible, can you include an explanation of whats wrong, beyond a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Post _working_ code, please. You can't define a module with a lowercase name. Besides, the classes in your code don't include the module and you don't call `print_header`. Furthermore, `Core_Class` looks odd, you should use `CoreClass` instead.

Comment: In your example `CoreClass` used in the `PrintHeader` module. Basically, its just wrong idea from the point of architecture. Your `PrintHeader` must "know nothing" about any other class (`CoreClass` or `UseClass`). And weird thing: `print_header` is not printing header, but `header` just implements that functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of working code, I'm remoting into a unix enviroment without the ability to take code out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you want to implement something like this:

```
module PrintHeader
  def print_header
    puts header
  end
end

class CoreClass
  include PrintHeader

  def header
    'old header'
  end
end

class UseClass < CoreClass
  def header
    'New header'
  end
end

core = CoreClass.new
use = UseClass.new

core.header
# => 'old header'
core.print_header
# old header
# => nil
use.header
# => 'New header'
use.print_header
# New header
# => nil
```